# Problems with State Management with Nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have been coding for about 9 months. I am starting to dabble with state and it has been a struggle at best, so I apologize if this question is very basic.

I'm using Nextjs, Prisma as my ORM, and PostgreSQL for my Database.

I am creating a Todo app and I am trying to make it so that when the user clicks the edit button, the edit form pops up and a save button renders in place of the edit button.

I'm trying to use [newTitle, setNewTitle] to make and set the new to-do item and [isEditing, setIsEditing] to set the editing state. Kind of self-explanatory.

I'm trying to create a handle change function that takes in the FormEvent, sets the newTitle state, then calls it in the input field. if isEditing = true, render save button(and input)
if isEditing = false, render edit button(and label)

[image: This is what my Todo app looks like at the moment]

Here's my event handler and my state variables

```
export default function TodoItem({ task }: TodoItemProps) {
  const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState("");
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);



  function handleChange(e: React.FormEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //@ts-ignore
    const title = e.target.title.value;
    //@ts-ignore
    const setIsEditing = e.target.isEditing;
    console.log("sanity check")
    //@ts-ignore
    dispatch({
      type: "edited",
      text: newTitle,
    })
    // router.push("/");
  }
```

I'm using input and then trying to use a ternary operator to toggle the Edit and Save buttons but clearly, I am doing something wrong

```
      <form onSubmit={handleChange} className="flex gap-1 items-center">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={newTitle}
          onChange={(e) =>
            //@ts-ignore
            dispatch({
              type: "edited",
              task: {
                ...task,
                id: task.id,
              }
            })
          }
        />

        {isEditing ? (
          <div className="group relative focus: text-slate-400 hover:text-blue-500">
            <button
              onClick={() =>
                setNewTitle("")
              }
            >
              Save
            </button>
          </div>
        ) :
          <div className="group relative focus: text-slate-400 hover:text-blue-500">
            <button
              onClick={() =>
                setIsEditing(true)
              }
            >
              Edit
            </button>
          </div>
        }
```

Here's my change route and my Prisma schema

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { prisma } from "@/db"; 

export async function PATCH(req: Request) {
    const { id, complete } = await req.json()

    const updatedTask = await prisma.todo.update({
        where: {
            id: id,
        },
        data: {
            id: id,
            complete: complete,
        },
    })

    return NextResponse.json(updatedTask)
}
```

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
//Learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Todo {
  id        String   @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  title     String
  complete  Boolean  @default(false)
}
```

In case I need to post it here is my layout.tsx

```
useEffect( () => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/getall')
  .then(res => {
    dispatch({ type: "getData", payload: { data: res.data } });
  })
}, [])

  const [tasks, dispatch] = useReducer(
    tasksReducer,
    []
  );
  return (

    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${inter.className} bg-slate-800 text-slate-100 container mx-auto p-4`}>
        <TasksContext.Provider value={tasks}>
          {/* @ts-ignore */}
          <TasksDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
            {children}
          </TasksDispatchContext.Provider>
        </TasksContext.Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

I apologize for this post being so long. I've been working on trying to solve this issue for a week and it is extremely frustrating. If someone could help me I would greatly appreciate it. In case I need to provide more information I will.

**EDIT**:  [image: Edit button click error]

**SECOND EDIT**  EDITED REDUCER AND TODOITEM.TSX

```
case 'edited': {
  axios.put(
    'http://localhost:3000/api/updated',
    { id: action.task.id, title: action.task.title }
  )

  return tasks.map(t => {
    if (t.id === action.task.id) {
      return action.task;
    } else {
      return t;
    }
  });     
}
```

```
"use client";

import { useState, useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { TasksDispatchContext } from "./TasksContext";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
//*useState is a react hook that allows you to use state in a functional component

type TodoItemProps = {
  task: {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    complete: boolean;
  };
};
//*What my todoitem components looks like when I call it in other functions
//*onChange event listener is used to toggle the todo item and pass an id to the database

export default function TodoItem({ task }: TodoItemProps) {
  const [showDelete, setShowDelete] = useState(false);
  const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState("");
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useContext(TasksDispatchContext);
  const router = useRouter();

  function handleChange(e: React.FormEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //@ts-ignore
    const editedTitle = e.target.title.value;
    setNewTitle(editedTitle);
    //@ts-ignore
  }

  console.log(handleChange)
  return (

    <li
      onMouseEnter={() => setShowDelete(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setShowDelete(false)}
      className="flex gap-1 items-center"
    >
      <input
        id={task.id}
        type="checkbox"
        className="cursor-pointer peer"
        checked={task.complete}
        onChange={(e) =>
          //@ts-ignore
          dispatch({
            type: "changed",
            task: {
              ...task,
              complete: e.target.checked,
            },
          })
        }
      />

      <label
        htmlFor={task.id}
        className="group relative cursor-pointer peer-checked:line-through"
      >
        {task.title}
      </label>

      <label htmlFor={task.id}> {newTitle} </label>

      {showDelete ? (
        <div className="group relative focus:text-slate-400 hover:  text-blue-500">
            <button
              onClick={(e) => 
                setIsEditing(true) }
            >
              Edit
            </button>
          {/* </input> */}
        </div>
      ) : isEditing && showDelete ? (

      <form className="flex text-left group relative focus: text-slate-400 hover:text-blue-500"
        onSubmit={handleChange}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={newTitle}
          onChange={() => setIsEditing(false)}
          className=" flex gap-2 flex-col w-1rem"
        />
        <div>
          <button
            className="flex text-left"
            onClick={(e) =>
              setNewTitle(e.target.value)
            }
          >
            Save
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      ) : null}

      {showDelete ? (
        <div className="group relative focus: text-slate-400 hover:text-red-500">
          <button
            onClick={() =>
              //@ts-ignore
              dispatch({
                type: "deleted",
                id: task.id,
              })
            }
          >
            Delete
          </button>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </li>
  );
}
```

[This is what I get in my console when I try to hit the edit button. Which is why I pasted my Todoitem.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk7a1.png)

Comment: what's the issue exactly?

Comment: Sorry. I should've included that. When I try to click on "Edit" I get an error. I will modify my question and display the error at the bottom

Comment: seems an issue with reducer, are you handling the `edited` case in reducer?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case, but it seems like you have a `switch`-statement inside `TasksContext.tsx`. Did you define a case for `"edited"` action? If so, is there a `break` at the end to prevent [fall-through](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#breaking_and_fall-through)?

Comment: I don't think I did. This is my first time using reducers and context with state

Comment: Could you add the relevant contents of `TasksContext.tsx` to the question? [\[edit\]](/posts/76965895/edit)

Comment: @3limin4t0r I'm sorry I didn't see your comment. I pasted my relevant reducer as well as a picture of my console in my inspector to show what happens when I hit the edit button. And pasted the Todoitem.tsx file in its entirety.

Comment: The `"edited"` case looks fine to me. You don't have a `break`, but you `return` from the function, which also works. Are you passing the correct value to the switch statement? eg. `switch (action.type) {`? Is your reducer function correctly accepting its arguments? eg. `function tasksReducer(tasks, action) {`

Comment: @3limin4t0r Yes it is. All the rest of my cases work. I can Add, change(which is mark a todo as done), and delete a todo. The only one I cant get is Edit/Save.